# Stick hearder is not working in some table

Tags: css, html-table, header, sticky

I have a scenario where the header should freeze/stick till that table is scrolled.
I used the following css, it worked on some tables but not on others.

```css
.Tree-Table-Header thead tr {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

following is the HTML Structure.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Don't post images of code - post the code itself! Edit your question and convert your code to a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.